# Adding a popup to com_users in joomla

Tags: joomla, popup

I want to add a popup and a trigger for that popup in com_users( i.e Users page) and load a external link into that popup. I have added a button next to the "Add a note" button but i am new to Joomla so i don't know how to add popup functionality to it. I have read that it is not recommended to change the core files in Joomla, is this also a core file ? What is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Any file that comes with Joomla's default installation is a core file. We do sometimes modify core files (especially for optimization purposes), but that creates overhead in the website's maintenance.

As for your case, the best way to do this is to create a copy of the administrator template that you're using, use that copy instead, and, modify the `administrator/templates/[new-template]/com_users/users/default.php` file. This way your changes will not be overwritten by a Joomla update.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm new to joomla and when i tried to add the button it is not showing up in the admin UI. Can you tell me the procedure to add a button with a popup functionality or direct me to any tutorial explaining the same ? Thanks in advance